# Magento 2 -How to change the format datetime with yyyy/mm/dd of DOB in customer edit

Tags: magento2, customer, locale

although I changed the locale of my account to Japan time. But it's display format of en_US.

[image]

Comment: i see this file that control the format : vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/date.htm